# MATlab neural network to android

Tags: android, matlab, neural-network

Is there a way to use trained mathlab neural network in to android.
Ex: i have trained neural network which recognise the numbers.Neural network is built using matlab.How can I use this trained neural network in an android app to recognize letters in an images getting from the mobile camera.

Comment: Although Android devices are getting more powerful every year, there might not be enough cycles to run a neural network.  Consider that Google implements speech recognition by streaming the audio to speech-to-text servers and returning results.  You might need to do something similar and send image data to servers that run your neural network and receive the recognition results.

Comment: I think it should be pretty easy. You you must know parameters of your neural network, weights, connections, layers. Then you should create tool for exporting it, to java version. It's neural network - you don't need any magic.

Comment: how to create tools to export them??? is there already implemented methods to import them